# Modify Usage string on Click command line interface on Windows

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I have a Python package called `tdsm`that I have converted for the first time to a command-line interface using Armin Ronacher's [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) package. I have set my scripts up within this directory structure:

[image]

Also I have created a `setup.py` file:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='tdsm',
    version='0.1',
    py_modules=['tdsm.scripts.data_manager',
                'tdsm.scripts.visuals'],
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[
        'click',
        'numpy',
        'scipy',
        'pandas',
        'wand',
        'matplotlib',
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        tdsm=tdsm.main:cli
    ''',
)
```

After a `pip install --editable .`, I get it working, up to a point:

```
# tdsm --help
```

Now emits:

```
Usage: tdsm-script.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  TDSM standard workflow -- typical sequence of commands:

      `init <path>` or `open <path>`: to set up the project or to open
      a new session on an existing project.

      `plot`: framework for setting up plots, display layers, and styling.

Options:

  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:

  init     Set up a project from scratch.
  plot     Initialize a plotting session.
```

Note the usage statement says *Usage: **tdsm-script.py** [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...* and not *Usage: **tdsm** [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...* as I believe it should. Since I am expecting this to be used by non-programmers, I don't want users delving through the system looking for a non-existent file...

Poring through the docs I can see how to change every aspect of the help text but not this initial reference to **`tdsm-script.py`**. Any pointers on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The issue was resolved in the [GitHub bug discussion thread](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/click/issues/365) by [Markus Unterwaditzer](https://github.com/untitaker). I reproduce it here for the record.

One just calls the command (or group, in my case) with an explicit `prog_name` argument, thus:

```
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.command(short_help='Set up a project from scratch.')
def init():
    pass

@cli.command(short_help='Initialise a plotting session.')
def plot():
    pass

cli(prog_name='tdsm')  # Call with explicit `prog_name`
```

On installing the package, the right Usage is reported:

```
# tdsm --help
Usage: tdsm [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not the only one with this problem. Judging from your screenshot it looks like you're on Windows, and it's [an open bug with Click](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/click/issues/365).

The problem is that Click appears to be autodetecting the program's name from `argv[0]`. See [the code in core.py](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/click/blob/master/click/core.py#L668) that does this.

The bug report link above suggests some hackish ways of getting around this, including monkey-patching. Unfortunately the last comment on the bug is from July 28 -- perhaps mention on that thread that you're also having this issue. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @ternus -- yes indeed I am on Windows and I will support the bug report...